# How to make my transaction commit in ActiveMQ, when my process is done successfully at the client side

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

```
<route>
        <from
            uri="jms:queue:inBox?concurrentConsumers=20" />

        <camel:process ref="processor1" />
        <transacted/>
        <camel:process ref="Processor2" />
    </route>
```

once my Processor 2 is successful then the inbox queue has to de-queue the message from activeMQ. Currently it is dequeuing the messages at the JMS Endpoint.

```
<bean id="jmsTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
</bean> 


<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory"
    class="com.mypackage.EncryptionAwareActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
    <property name="userName" value="admin" />
    <property name="password" value="@PASSWORD@" />
</bean>


<bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
    init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="20" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
</bean>


<bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="50" />
    <property name="deliveryPersistent" value="true" />
    <property name="transacted" value="true" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jmsTransactionManager" />
</bean>


<bean id="jms" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig" />

</bean>
```

So I'm using this configuration like this and setting transacted as true And also i have used JMS transnational manager.

Comment: Put transacted right after `<from>`, and set `transacted=true` on the JMS component. See the docs at: http://camel.apache.org/transactional-client.html. And if you have a copy of the CiA book then it has a full chapter on transactions. And you can also look at some of the CiA2 source code examples (for free): https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2/blob/master/chapter12/riderautoparts-partner/src/test/resources/camelinaction/RiderAutoPartsPartnerTransactedTest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not enough to just add `<transacted/>` to your route. You also need to configure your JMS component to support transactions.

I suggest you read the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.2/html-single/transaction_guide/index#FMRTxnJMS) thoroughly. 
Below is a relevant code example from the link:

```
<bean id="jmstx" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent"> 
  <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig" /> 
</bean> 

<bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration"> 
  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/> 
  <property name="transactionManager" ref="jmsTransactionManager"/> 
  <property name="transacted" value="true"/>
  <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_CONNECTION"/>
</bean> 

<bean id="jmsTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
  <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://broker1?brokerConfig=xbean:tutorial/activemq.xml"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Please see the edited question, i'm using that configuration in that manner.